# Cross Compiling C# code to Colibri iMX6 (Linux) exe using MonoDevelop in Ubuntu environment

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, cross-compiling

I want to develop an embedded application using Colibri iMX6 module (Linux OS). I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on virtual machine and have monodevelop installed. I want to write my application in C# and cross compile it using mono for arm processor.

Can someone guide me through the process of creating an arm executable file using mono?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One of the great things about .NET is that you don't *need* to cross-compile anything. CIL assemblies are, by nature, platform- and architecture-independent -- unless your assemblies link against platform-specific assemblies (such as the WPF assemblies on Windows), or if the project file build settings target specific processor architectures (like x86 or x64/x86-64). If you don't link to any platform-dependent assemblies (unless they exist on your target platform) and target the AnyCPU architecture, then assemblies you build on one system should run anywhere that mono is available.

Comment: Hi Dustin, Thank you for the input. I am sorry I could not explain the complete environment setup. It is as follows:

Comment: Colibri IMX6 running Linux and
PC: Ubuntu (Virtual)

I complied a C# code using mono (ubuntu). The exe executes in Ubuntu but when I transfer the exe to arm-linux, I get an error "cannot execute binary file: exec format error". Due to this error I believe I need a cross compiler that cross-complies C# code in ubuntu for arm-linux. 

Please let me know if you have any input on this. 

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't directly execute CIL assemblies. You need to use the `mono` command to execute them, like  so:

      mono some_net_executable.exe

Comment: For the sake of convenience, you can set up binfmt_misc on your ARM system, which will allow you to execute .NET executable assemblies without needing to invoke `mono` directly. The instructions are here: http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/#registering-exe-as-non-native-binaries-linux-only

Comment: A little bit of background: .NET assemblies are a lot like compiled Java .class files (which  I assume you're familiar with), in that they don't contain native executable code -- instead, they contain bytecode that gets JIT-compiled at runtime by the CLR, the virtual machine component of an  ordinary .NET framework implementation (such as Mono). This is why they're platform-  and architecture-independent. A cross-compiler is thus totally unnecessary.

Comment: The error  you  got, by the way, is due to the Linux kernel not recognizing the executable format that .NET uses: standard Linux executables are ELF format, while .NET uses the PE executable format. This is why you need to execute .NET executables by passing them as an argument to the `mono` command. The binfmt_misc setup I mentioned above makes the Linux kernel recognize .NET PE executables as executable files, and ensures that they're executed using mono.